# How to display image and text in same line in mobile device using css?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am able to display the image and text in the same line in desktop but In a mobile device, it is not displayed in the same line.It is displaying image and below text. I have to display both in the same line. Would you help me in this?

Below image:-I am getting output like this in mobile device.

[image]

Output:  I have to display both i the same line.like displaying in desktop

```css
.amazon-section{
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: table;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 38px 5px;
    border-radius: 04px;
    webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    font-family:"Arcon-Regular";
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.amazon-section img{
    width:100px;
    padding:10px;
    position: relative;
    right: 20px;
}
.amazon-content{
    display:inline-block;
}
.amazon-content h2{
    font-size:18px;
    color:#53585F !important;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="amazon-section">
     <div class="amazon">
         <img src="images/amazon.png">
         <div class="amazon-content">
             <h2 class="amazon-text">Lorem ipsum dolor tetur<br /> adipiscing elit.</h2>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: format your code better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and leave  your html a little cleaner and leaner.

Basically, you can easily control both vertical and horizontal centering with `justify-content` (horizontal or main axis) and `align-items` (vertical or cross axis), which you can set on the container/parent directly.

```
.amazon-section
{
 text-align:center;
 background-color: #fff;
 display: table;
 margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
 padding: 0px 38px 5px;
 border-radius: 04px;
 webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
 font-family:"Arcon-Regular";
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.amazon {  /*set children to be centered vertically and horizontally*/
 display: flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
}
.amazon-section img /*children need no positional css*/
{
 width:100px;
 padding:10px;
}
.amazon-content h2
{
 font-size:18px;
 color:#53585F !important;
 font-weight: 600;
}
```

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZNmGj)

Comment: Thanks For replying Sweaver2112, It it working for me.upvote form my side

Answer (score 1):

This piece of CSS will hide all `<br>` elements that are directly nested in a `<h2>` element at browser widths below 768px...  In this case, achieving your goal as I understand it.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   h2 > br { display: none; }
}
```

---

### Update

I originally thought it was the text itself you wanted on 1 line.
In order to keep the image along side the text, I would suggest using CSS3's `flex`.  For example:

```
.amazon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;  /* <- Helps with vertical alignment */
}
```

You can also specify how much of the horizontal proportions you want each of the children to occupy by default, and whether you wish to allow them to shrink or grow, etc.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Mr.ne1410s, I add my image to the question, What I need and what I am getting.  Please check it and help me in this

Comment: Ah ok - I think if you put `display: flex` on your area that contains the image and the text, then the content will stay on the same line by default..  I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.ne1410s, I will wait for your reply

Answer (score 0):

```css
.amazon-section
{

text-align:center;
background-color: #fff;
display: table;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
padding: 0px 38px 5px;
border-radius: 04px;
webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
position: relative;
top: 20px;
font-family:"Arcon-Regular";
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.amazon-section > img
{
width:100px;
padding:10px;
position: relative;
right: 20px;
}
.amazon{
 vertical-align:top;
 display:inline-block;
}
.amazon-content
{
display:inline-block;

}
.amazon-content > h2
{
vertical-align:top;
font-size:18px;
color:#53585F !important;
font-weight: 600;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
 <div class="amazon-section">
 <div class="amazon">
 <img src="images/amazon.png">
 <div class="amazon-content">
<h2 class="amazon-text">Lorem ipsum dolor tetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your amazon-section contains the image that you both gave 100px.

Comment: Sorry Mr.jmag, But in mobile It is not displaying in same line.

Comment: Same as it is I have to display in mobile device

Comment: I just finish editing it. Check if its what you want.

Comment: Mr.jmag, I add my image to the question, What I need and what I am getting.  Please check it and help me in this

Comment: Same output I need in mobile device

Comment: top:15; might be causing your text to move down in addition to the margin.